# Basemap: create figure with graph and map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a map with basemap and would like to put a graph in the same figure.
Until now I did this:

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-32.5,urcrnrlat=-10,llcrnrlon=-57.5,urcrnrlon=-40,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')
x, y = m(lon, lat) # compute map proj coordinates.
parallels = np.arange(-50.,20,5.)
meridians = np.arange(-90.,0.,5.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)
m.scatter(x,y,s=abs(100.*np.array(correlacoes[i])),c=correlacoes[i],norm=mc.Normalize(vmin=-1.0,vmax=1.0))
m.drawcoastlines()
m.colorbar()
pyl.title(nomvar + ' cp ' + str(i+1) + '   v.e. %5.2f' % varexp[i])
pyl.savefig(dir_pro+projeto+arquivo + '_cp%3.3i' % (i+1) + '.png')   
pyl.clf()    
pyl.plot(indicesfs,fs[i])
pyl.title(nomvar + ' cp ' + str(i+1) + '   v.e. %5.2f' % varexp[i])
pyl.savefig(dir_pro+projeto+arquivo + '_fs%3.3i' % (i+1) + '.png')   
pyl.clf()
```

But in this way I have two figures, and I would like to put both (graph and map) in the same figure
Is there any way to adjust the map and graph position and obtain this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question but you can use `subplot()` in matplotlib to produce multiple plots on the same figure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using m.plot() instead of pyl.plot()? (and no clf() in between)